# Webpack proxy not working

Tags: proxy, webpack, vue.js, webpack-dev-server

I'm now writing a vue project and I want to send some api requests to the remote server.

So I add this in my `webpack.dev.conf.js`:

```
devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
    noInfo: true,
    hot:true,
    open:true,
    proxy: {
        '/api': {
            target: 'http://47.93.247.233',
            secure: false,
            changeOrigin: true,
            pathRewrite: {'^/api' : ''}
        }
    }
},
```

But I still get 404 in my browser.

[image: headers]

[image: preview]

And I'm sure the server is ok:

[image: postman]

I think maybe the webpack devServer didn't forward my http request to the remote server. Is there anything wrong in my code? Or, can I try some other methods?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You server is not ok. Look at your second screenshot, the status is also "404", and the title is also "Page not found at /login/".
Maybe your configuration is working fine, it's just your backend that is really throwing 404

Comment: @EvaldoBratti I'm so sorry that I forget my login url is '/account/api' instead of '/login', but I find this problem still exists. I have updated my question with another api ( which is much more simple than 'login' ).

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use

```
proxyTable: {...},
```

instead of

```
proxy{}
```

I'm running with webpack version 3.10.0 with npm v 5.6.0 and this works fine!
May be, you will try "logLevel: 'debug' too, to see some hints in your terminal window.